# How to show a php image in imageview?

Tags: java, php, android, image, imageview

I am trying with this code and it's not working.
How can I download that pic and show it.

my java code

```
private ImageView iv;
private Bitmap bitmap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showprofile);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.virus);
    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://getbloodbd.org/image.php?no=4");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my xml code is

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="org.getbloodbd.getbloodbd.ShowprofileActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_showprofile">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/virus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and my php code is and in webview method it's work fine, but image view not working, but i need image view method .

```
   <?php include 'config.php';header("Content-type: image/gif" );$no=$_GET['no']; $dn = mysql_query('select  image from images where no="'.$no.'"'); $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn); $data = $dnn['image'];echo base64_decode($data);?>
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: give the full url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do code for image loading.
There is famous library for image loading for android application, Picasso will take care of call retry, also save image in app cache. So, same image not download every time.

Dependency for picasso is

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Picasso.with(context).load(your_image_url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can load the image from the url like below

```
URL url = new URL("image full path");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

another way to load the image

```
private Bitmap bmp;

   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {                  
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                InputStream in = new URL(IMAGE_URL).openStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // log error
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (bmp != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

   }.execute();
```

Please [reference](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/imageview/android-how-to-load-image-from-url-in-imageview/) here.
Please have a try

Answer (score 0):

Follow This link [Click Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120802025411/http://developer.aiwgame.com/imageview-show-image-from-url-on-android-4-0.html).

Make sure you have the following permissions set in your AndroidManifest.xml to access the internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Ok...Cool follow above link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use library Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

import

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Use:

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://getbloodbd.org/image.php?no=4").into(iv);
```

Or if you want get Bitmap:

```
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load("http://getbloodbd.org/image.php?no=4").listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            iv.setImageBitmap(resource);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for getting image from server and load into ImageView with a lots of option.

- Sample for Picasso

  ```
  Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .centerCrop()
  .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
  .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
  .into(imageView);
  ```
- Sample for Glide

  ```
  GlideApp
  .with(context)
  .load(url)
  .centerCrop()
  .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
  .into(imageView);
  ```

don't forget to add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```